# Ember and Express: let Ember handle routes instead of Express?

Tags: node.js, ember.js, express

This might be a dumb question, but I'm serving an Ember app I made using `ember-cli` on an Express server, but when I try to access various routes, my Express app errors, saying that no route exists (which is true, because I defined the routes in Ember, not Express).  How should I resolve this, and is this normal behavior?

My Ember router:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', {path: '/' });
  this.route('portkey');
  this.route('login');
});
```

My Express routes are just an API that do not serve any of the Ember routes, since `localhost:1234` will automatically load `index.html`.

Comment: are your end points defined in your express app? You have to have the routes, endpoints, resources whatever you want to call them defined in your express app as well.

Comment: Assuming that your Ember routes are using location history(means no hash), and trying to access those routes directly rather inside from Ember Application, you have to make sure first about loading Ember application before applying the route through Express server. Although its quite easy to redirect the html page which has ember Application, only challenge will be to make sure ember understand redirecting to the specified url.

Comment: @CodeJack can you clarify this a little bit?  My routes work when I use the {{link-to}} helper and click them off of the root URL.  Is there a way I can load the ember application when I type in the URL directly?

Comment: the pages should be `localhost:1234/#/`, `localhost:1234/#/portkey`, `localhost:1234/#/login`. Also, you don't need to specify index. It's automatically assumed to exist and be `/` path.

Answer (score 4):

I've never had a problem using the Ember Router instead of the Express router. All I do is have 1 express route (for '/') which displays my Ember application index.html (well actually index.ejs) page. Not promising this is *the* right way to do it, but it's how I do it and it works for me.

So start with this.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {});
});
```

That's your express route. Now your ember routing.

```
App.Router.map( function() {
    this.route("about", { path: "/about" });
    this.route("favorites", { path: "/favorites" });
});
```

So as of now you have a routing structure that looks like the following:

```
yourdomain.com/             --> index.ejs displayed via express routing
              /#/           --> this is the ember index route
              /#/about      --> this is the ember about route
              /#/favorites  --> this is the ember favorites route
```

Within the index.ejs file you have the basic ember file linking to your ember application.

Now onto your linking problems...

If you use the ember router, then make sure you are linking to your different routes the correct way. (Remember, ember routes start with /#/someroute).

So your links in handlebars should be something like:

```
{{#link-to 'some_page'}}Go to some page{{/link}}
```

**NOT**

```
<a href="some_page">Go to some page</a>
```

Using the second, express would be trying to handle the routing but by using the first, ember is handling the routing.

So if you really think about it, you can have as many ember applications as your little heart disires because each ember application is linked to that current page in the express routing.

For example on my website, I use two routes (plus a bunch of REST routes obviously): `login.ejs` and `index.ejs`.

So for [my site](http://budgeter.matthewtporter.com), I have the following routes:

```
mysite.com/             
          /#/           
          /#/budget     
          /#/history     
          /#/profile    
          /#/logout     

mysite.com/login#/
                #/register
                #/forget
```

I hope this helps you a little bit.

**EDIT**

`/#/` is a convention to tell ember you are routing via its router.

Think of it like this: Ember is a single-page framework. So when you link from page to page in ember, you aren't *truely* changing pages. You are just removing dom elements and replacing them with new ones. But if you go to `/budget` on the server, you are now going to a whole new page, not just the `/#/budget` section of the ember application.

I think you are just confusing what the ember router really is.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  Unfortunately, that didn't work for me.  My links work fine, its only when I try to type in the URL directly that the Express error shows up.  I'm not quite familiar with the hash in the URL, but I think if you try a similar example with (your site)[http://budgeter.matthewtporter.com/budget], there is also an error.

Comment: It should be budgeter.matthewtporter.com/#/budget. Its the `#/` that seperates the ember router from the express router. My "budget" route only exists within ember (thusly being `/#/budget`, not `/budget`.)

Comment: @jjwon to load the ember route directly, you have to use `/#/` convention. That's why it is there. There is a clear cut difference between `/budget` and `/#/budget`. One goes to the express route, the other the ember route.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Right now when I enter in the `/#/my_page` it redirects me back to the `/my_page` which triggers the Express error.  Is there any setting that controls this?

Comment: Hmmm... Not that I can think of off the top of my head. I am at work so I can't even view my own website or code but you can look at my repo to see if you notice anything. (http://github.com/m-porter/bearded-wookie) If you don't find anything, I'll be more helpful in a few hours.

Also, could you put your current ember route code snippet in your original post?

Comment: I understand that `/#/` is a way to tell Ember to render new routes inside Ember.  However, when I type in `/#/my_page`, I am automatically redirected to `/mypage`.  In addition, when I click on links (structured like `{{#link-to 'login'}}LOGIN HERE{{/link-to}}`), I am not redirected to `/#/login`, but rather `/login`.  Let me know if something there is wrong.

Comment: Alright, I figured it out.  It was a configuration in `ember-cli` which I did not expect.  In `app/config/environment.js`, you need to set `locationType: 'hash'` in order to ensure that the `/#/` is appended to different link locations.

Comment: If you would have said you were using `ember-cli` i would have suggested that a long time ago haha. oh well. glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues when trying to directly access any part of my Ember project other than index.html. From there I could easily navigate where I wanted, but it meant that providing someone a link or refreshing the page would fail.

Example: `/accounts` would fail.
`/#/accounts` would successfully redirect to `/accounts` however refreshing still would not work.

Solution:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('accounts');
});

Router.reopen({
  location: 'hash'
});
```

Now all of my links are prefixed with # such as `/#/accounts`, refreshing and direct-linking works as expected.

Comment: where you have added this solution. I mean in which file

Comment: Included in `app/router.js`. Alternatively you can extend the router with `location` from config instead of reopening the router.