# How do you handle routing in a Node + Ember application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js

I have a Node + Ember application. I ran into an issue around routes. Both Node and Ember handle routes and I have some routes that I would like Node to handle but some, I want Ember to handle. For instance, when the page loads, Node's router kicks in so any route I declare in Ember is useless.

Assume that I have a route called 'settings' in Ember JS. When I navigate to 'http://myapp.com/settings' by using the {{#link-to}} helper from another view in Ember, I can see the page. However, once I am on that page and hit reload, I get a 404 because Node's router is called and that route is not declared in Node. How do I resolve this?

Comment: answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835493/ember-and-express-let-ember-handle-routes-instead-of-express

Comment: Actually, the answer there explains my problem again. It doesn't solve it.

Comment: If you use the ember router, then make sure you are linking to your different routes the correct way. (Remember, ember routes start with /#/someroute).

Comment: The issue is that the Ember doesn't even get called when I directly navigate to the URL because the server looks for that route in Node.

Comment: which part of : Remember, ember routes start with /#/someroute is unclear to you?

Comment: Dude, I don't need the #. I'm using Ember CLI and URLs in my application don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use node but I imagine the concept is probably the same for you as it is for my app (I'm using Java Spring). You should modify your route to `app.get('/*')` or however you use wildcards in node and return Ember's index.html. So basically, any url under / aka all of them get your Ember app, not just the / route

Ember handles the rest. Take a look at this thread (its for nginx, but again the principal is the same): http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-serve-all-routes-on-a-production-server-exactly/6372/2

In case that link goes down at some point in the future, here's the useful nginx configuration that rewrites all rules under / except for `assets` with the ember index.html page:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name my.domain.com;
    root /path/to/app/root;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ /index.html break;
    }

    location /assets/ {
        # do nothing and let nginx handle this as usual
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point. The next step then would be, if someone visited say mydomain.com/register and because of the nginx configuration, we redirect this request to Ember, how do we pass the intension of redirecting to register to Ember? There's no way to pass that information with the above configuration. It would only serve the default Ember route (the Index route). We need to go to register.

Comment: Ember should serve the correct route even if you return the index.html page. Did it not work for you?

Comment: How would Ember know to do that? I have a rule in Node that captures the /sign-in route and sends the user to index.html. However, the Ember route that gets fired when Node redirects to index.html is the index route and not the sign-in route. What am I missing?

Comment: index.html is the starting point to your Ember app. I don't know the internals I figure it looks at the browser history to serve the right route. Index.html is not the same thing as the index route

Comment: what is your config/environment.js file?

Comment: I understand. However, redirecting to the index.html file will fire off the index route by default since Ember doesn't have any context of what other route it needs to go to, correct? Here's my environment.js file: http://www.codeshare.io/WDVf8.